# changing case in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe x :

```
sequence score
AAtttGG   2
CCCgttT   3
```

I want the output

```
sequence score
AATTTGG   2
CCCGTTT   3
```

so that all sequences are uppercase. I would appreciate a oneliner that will do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the vectorised [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) method [`upper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.upper.html#pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.upper):

```
In [98]:

df.sequence = df.sequence.str.upper()
df
Out[98]:
  sequence  score
0  AATTTGG      2
1  CCCGTTT      3
```